# Pentaho Load Plain Text File w/ ASCII separator

Tags: ascii, pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to use Spoon / Kettle to upload a plain text file that is separated by ASCII characters. I can see all the data when I preview the content of the file in Kettle, but no records load when I try to preview rows on the "Content" tab.

According to my research, Kettle should understand my field separator when typed as "$[value]" which in my case is "$[01]". Here's a description of the file structure:

Each file in the feed is in plain text format, separated into columns and rows. Each record has the same set of fields. The following are the delimiters for 
each field and record:

Field Separator (FS): SOH (ASCII character 1)

Record Separator (RS) : STX (ASCII character 2) + “n”

Any record starting with a “#” and ending with the RS should be treated as a comment by the ingester and ignored. The data provider has also generated a column header line at the beginning of the file, listing field data types.

So my input parameters are:

Filetype: Fixed

Separator: $[01]

Enclosure:

Escape:

...

Format: DOS

Encoding: US-ASCII

Length: Characters

I'm unable to read any records, and I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. Would ingesting this data with java inside of kettle be a better method?

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide sample Data for the same?

Comment: Depending on your O.S, windows or linux, there are different control characters to be monitored. if you want your separator to be the literal $[01], what you need to type is \$\[01\] ... \ being the escape character.